# How does the opening angle of a light source change the light field at a certain distance

Tags: visible-light

I want to simulate the Intensity distribution of a light source on a plane some distance "d" away from the light source. If I assume the light source to homogenously emit light in all directions, I can do it just using the cosine-cubed law:

$$ E = \frac{I*cos^3(θ)}{d^2} $$

My question is: If my light source is an LED, for example, and has a specific opening angle, how can and must I adjust the formula above to account for the opening angle of the LED?

Answer (score 0):

The law is just the same, if the intensity ist the same over the whole angle, otherwise it ist the same law but $I=I(\phi)$

Comment: Thank you. And I=I(ϕ) should be a gaussian, right?

Comment: I don't know the intensity curve of a LED